# 'Install app for SharePoint': Access denied

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, visual-studio-2013

We get the following error when trying to deploy a SharePoint hosted app in SharePoint Online. It worked fine till yesterday.

> Install app for SharePoint: 
>   Uploading the app for SharePoint...  
>   Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': Access denied.  
>   You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource. 
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ========== 
>   ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

I have full control on the site collection. We tried with other users who have full control. But no luck.

Also, I tried creating a test app with default template on Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 in various machines. No luck.

The problem is limited to one site collection only. I can create apps on another site collection where I have full control.

Answer (score 0):

In the application, Please try to login to the site before deploying the app. You can login by changing site in Properties tab of the project. 
Note: Try to login with different site and then try with your Source site

[image]
[image]